# Mark Duplicate Rows in DataTable

Tags: c#

I am currently using the following code to show me duplicate entries.

```
private static void CheckDataTable(DataTable dt)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int a = i + 1; a < dt.Rows.Count; a++)
            {
                if (dt.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString() == dt.Rows[a]["ID"].ToString())
                    dt.Rows[i]["Duplicate"] = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

The `Duplicate` column is later integrated into a WPF DataGrid to color a cell. The method works quite ok but as soon as the DataTable has many rows, for example 180, the whole takes very long, because I go through with every cell change in the DataGrid the method again.

Is there a faster or even better way?

Comment: You are marking each record as 'true' for every duplicates you encounter. Are you sure you need to do that or you can just get the unique rows, grouped by the count of occurrences of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this: group rows by ID, and count where that id is greater than 0. That can be easily achieved using Linq.

```
private static void CheckDataTable(DataTable dt)
{
    var duplicateRows = dt.AsEnumerable()
        .GroupBy(r = > r[0])
        .Where(r = > r.Count() > 1)
        .SelectMany(r = > r)
        .ToList();

    duplicateRows.ForEach(r = > r["Duplicate"] = true);
}
```

or, to skip local variable:

```
dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r = > r[0])
    .Where(r = > r.Count() > 1)
    .SelectMany(r = > r)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(r = > r["Duplicate"] = true);
```

Comment: `SelectMany(r => r.ToList())` not simpler `SelectMany(r => r)`

Comment: @lomed, you're right, thanks. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the good response. It works great. But what do I do if I have edited a cell and this now needs the value false? I am sorry but I do not know so well about LinQ

Comment: @Hadda, you could set `Duplicate` column to `false` for each row and then check for duplicates. So, first line in could be `dt.AsEnumerable().ToList().ForEach(r => r["Duplicate"] = false);`

Comment: @Nino Works perfect. Thank you very much